# Error in function findFundamentalMat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use this code(source) to find fundamental matrix in opencv.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;    
int point_count = 100;
        vector<Point2f> points1(point_count);
        vector<Point2f> points2(point_count);

        // initialize the points here ... */
        for( int i = 0; i < point_count; i++ )
        {
           points1[i] = Point2f(10.0f, 20.0f);
           points2[i] = Point2f(0.3f, 40.0f);
        }

        Mat fundamental_matrix =
         findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);
```

but I am getting error in **findFundamentalMat** like this

```
undefined reference to `cv::findFundamentalMat(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, int, double, double, cv::_OutputArray const&)'
```

Please point out what I am doing wrong and be descriptive as I am new to OpenCv, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linker error. You need to include in your linker libraries the `calib3d` one, possibly others.

Comment: includeded calib3d, got error fatal error: calib3d: No such file or directory

Comment: Which OS are you on? What compiler do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux 4.4.0-42-generic, I am using opencv in eclipse

Comment: output of  pkg-config --libs opencv
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_viz -lippicv -lopencv_core

Comment: @RahulKSingh I'm seeing the `-lopencv_calib3d` already listed. You still get that error under these conditions?

Comment: after including opencv_calib3d in linkersetting, I manege to compile the code without any error without including opencv_calib3d in code.
But now i wondering how to print this fundamental matrix

Comment: @RahulKSingh So my answer solved your problem, right? Because "But now i wondering how to print this fundamental matrix" is another question (answer - the `opencv::Mat` has the `at(row, column)` method: use it to print your matrix the way you like)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows user, you need to include `calib3d.hpp` in order to use the findFundamentalMat function.

```
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
```